# Cobordism modelling fibration over $S^1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, cobordism

Let $X$ be a closed oriented manifold  which is a fibration over $S^1$ whose fiber $F$ is connected, i.e. $X\cong F\times[0,1]/\sim h$, for an $h\in \mathrm{Diff}(F)$. 
Suppose that $b_1(X)=1$.  Consider $\mathbb Z$-covering $\pi: \tilde X\to X$. As $b_1(X)=1$, the $\mathbb Z$-covering is unique up to isomorphism.

**Q** Can we always find a compact cobordism $W$ with $\partial W=Y\cup \bar Y$ such that:

1. $\tilde X\cong \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z} W_n$, where $W_n$ denotes the $n$-th. copy.
2. $W/\sim_Y\cong X$.
3. $b_1(W)=0$.

PS:

1. Thanks to Mike Miller for correcting the first version.
2. As $\tilde X\cong F\times \mathbb R$, I think if $b_1(W)=0$, then we have $b_1(F)=0$?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't always do this. Consider, for instance, 0-framed surgery on any non-trivial fibered knot. (Take the trefoil or figure eight knot as a concrete instance.) Then $H_1(\tilde{X}) = H_1(F)$ which is not zero. (Otherwise F would be a disk and your knot would be trivial). On the other hand, the standard Mayer-Vietoris calculation of $H_1(\tilde{X})$ as a union of the $W_n$ shows that $\oplus_n H_1(W_n) \to H_1(\tilde{X})$ is surjective. Hence $b_1(W_n)\neq 0$.

The Mayer-Vietoris argument is done many places, eg Rolfsen or Burde-Zieschang, or Milnor's *Infinite cyclic coverings*.

Comment: So, if $b_1(\tilde X)=0$, then we can always find such $W$?

Comment: No, you can't, at least in the classical dimension.  Take a non-trivial knot with Alexander polynomial 1; this is equivalent to $b_1(\tilde{W})=0$.  If $b_1(W)=0$ then $Y$ is a disk, which implies that your knot is trivial.  I'm not sure what happens in higher dimensions.